# Implementation of N array- Tree Structure in java

Tags: java

Having requirement to read Parent and children representation in tree structure.

1. Root    Parent      Child       Depth
2. AAA      -          -            0
3. AAA      AAA        BBB          1
4. AAA      AAA        CCC          1
5. AAA      BBB        BBB1         2
6. AAA      CCC        CCC1         2

As you can see it AAA is root element and has two child BBB and CCC.
again BBB and CCC has children so on.

Would like to have as one node mapped with all its children.

### Options

Created Treenode Class as mentioned below.

```
    public class TreeNode<T> {

     private final List<TreeNode<T>> children;
        private TreeNode<T> parent;
        private T data;
        private int depth;

        public TreeNode(T data) {
            // a fresh node, without a parent reference
            this.children = new ArrayList<>();
            this.parent = null;
            this.data = data;
            this.depth = 0; // 0 is the base level (only the root should be on there)
        }

        public TreeNode(T data, TreeNode<T> parent) {
            // new node with a given parent
            this.children = new ArrayList<>();
            this.data = data;
            this.parent = parent;
            this.depth = (parent.getDepth() + 1);
            parent.addChild(this);
        }

        public int getDepth() {
            return this.depth;
        }

        public void setDepth(int depth) {
            this.depth = depth;
        }

        public List<TreeNode<T>> getChildren() {
            return children;
        }

        public void setParent(TreeNode<T> parent) {
            this.setDepth(parent.getDepth() + 1);
            parent.addChild(this);
            this.parent = parent;
        }

        public TreeNode<T> getParent() {
            return this.parent;
        }

        public void addChild(T data) {
            TreeNode<T> child = new TreeNode<>(data);
            this.children.add(child);
        }

        public void addChild(TreeNode<T> child) {
            this.children.add(child);
        }

        public T getData() {
            return this.data;
        }

        public void setData(T data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        public boolean isRootNode() {
            return (this.parent == null);
        }

        public boolean isLeafNode() {
            return (this.children.size() == 0);
        }

        public void removeParent() {
            this.parent = null;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            String out = "";
            out += "Node: " + this.getData().toString() + " | Depth: " + this.depth + " | Parent: " + (this.getParent() == null ? "None" : this.parent.getData().toString()) + " | Children: " + (this.getChildren().size() == 0 ? "None" : "");
            for(TreeNode<T> child : this.getChildren()) {
                out += "\n\t" + child.getData().toString() + " | Parent: " + (child.getParent() == null ? "None" : child.getParent().getData());
            }
            return out;
        }
}
```

Received data as mentioned in above structure from DB as list

```
TreeNode<CompanyReport > root = null;
TreeNode<CompanyReport > firstChild = null;
for (CompanyReport report : reportList) {
    if (report.getDepth() == 0) {
         root =  new TreeNode(report);
    } 
    if (report .getDepth() == 1) {
        firstChild = new TreeNode<CompanyReport >(report, root);
    }
}
```

Here when Depth is 2 then want to map next child to its first child not to root element.
Could you please suggest how it should be done.

We can have deeper depth as well not restricted to 2 or 3 and it can not be binary tree structure as well. Its kind of n-array structure.

Comment: And what exactly is your question?

Comment: when further depth increases then how to map second child to it parent not to root element. Ex> BBB and CCC should be mapped with root element AAA and BBB1 should be mapped with BBB(its parent) and CCC1  should be mapped with CCC(its parent) . It can continue further depth like 3, 4,5 etc. Please provide suggestion on the same.

Comment: Please let me know if still question is not clear

Comment: How to map second child with first parent not to root element.